# How to differentiate between error exceptions and fatal exceptions in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I want to use two different kind of exceptions in my project:

1. Fatal exceptions. If something goes unexpectedly wrong, like a mysql query fails, I want to throw this kind of exception, without necessarily having to catch it. This exception means that I need to take some action, like logging a message, then showing an error, using CodeIgniter's show_error() function. The script should exit without continuing.
2. Error exception. If a user does something not allowed, such as enters letters into a numbers field or accesses a page he doesn't have permissions for, this exception should be thrown and caught.

I want to use both kinds of exceptions throughout the project. Number 2 is clear enough, but how do I go about doing exception 1? It would be great to not have to have two catch blocks for every try block, as the 1st type is global and should always be the same: log message, show error, exit. And lastly, in codeigniter, where would be the correct place to extend the Exception class?

Thanks.

Comment: may be this should help http://thecancerus.com/simple-way-to-add-global-exception-handling-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

**Fatal Exceptions**

[The link posted by Sunil above](http://thecancerus.com/simple-way-to-add-global-exception-handling-in-codeigniter/) is great for globally handling Fatal Exceptions. You want to be very careful about throwing these exceptions, and be sure that to the end user, the site doesn't look scary and broken - [humoring the user is always a good idea](https://www.google.com/search?q=error%20page).

**Error Exceptions**

I think you would be better off ***not*** treating errors like text in a numeric field as exceptions, because they ***do not disrupt the normal flow of the program's instructions.***

If a user enters an alpha into a numeric field and submits the form, your application should ***expect*** that a user may provide junk data, and you repeat the input process, which is the normal flow.

Here is how I handle scenario 2 in code igniter:

1. Extend `CI_Log` with `/application/libraries/MY_Log`
2. Add `MY_Log::$logs` to store messages in array if log level permits
3. The template hook gets the logs `MY_Log::get_logs()` then passes them on to the view that displays the appropriate [message boxes](https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20message%20boxes) for the log levels

I also implement a custom log level called `error_log`. This is for anything that I want to send to the log file without showing the user.